# New lines before and after blocks in clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I wish to have empty lines before and after blocks in my code. Astyle supports this ([Break-Blocks](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_break-blocks)). Is there a way to do this with clang-format? I already know about `KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks`, but that only keeps existing empty lines, if I understand correctly.